# export images to JPEG-XR with java?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, jai, jpeg-xr

Curious to try out exporting BufferedImages to JPEG-XR, but cannot find an export tool to add to a java workflow.  Preferably there is a a JAI plugin out there somewhere...   I googled [about](http://www.phpied.com/ie9-and-jpeg-xr-first-impressions/) to no avail.  Hopefully someone here can point us in the right direction for where to find this type of resource.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no publicly available JPEG-XR libraries in Java.

However, at http://teavuihuang.com/hdphoto/ is a J2ME app that appears to support the JPEG-XR format: this looks like the only Java artifact I've EVER seen that even mentions support for JPEG-XR. Maybe if you contact the author he may be persuaded to part with his JPEG-XR output code: it probably won't be JAI-compatible, but it'll be a start.

Let me know if you find anything..